# Using the JSON Library in Mono

Tags: c#, android, json, xamarin.android

How do i use the JSON Library in Monodroid using VisualStudio 2010. I cannot find it anywhere, though the Mono Assemblies Page says it should exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. Found it. Forgot to reference System.Json.